# Как реализовать меню через табы?

Tags: javascript

Всем привет.

Необходимо реализовать меню на сайте через табы.

В принципе нашел то что подойдет вот тут https://frontips.ru/variant-adaptivnyh-vkladok-tabs-na-javascript/

Но мне не нужно чтобы была изначально активная хоть какая то вкладка.

Как сделать чтобы изначально открытой вкладки с контентом не было?

Пробовал удалять ту часть кода, которая отвечает за установку активной по умолчанию и код ломается.

Подскажите пожалуйста.
Вот код прилагаю, кто переходить не хочет по ссылке

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => { // Структура страницы загружена и готова к взаимодействию

  const tabs = () => { // объявляем основную функцию для вкладок, чтобы вся логика была в одном месте
    const head = document.querySelector('.tabs__head') // ищем элемент с кнопками и записываем в константу
    const body = document.querySelector('.tabs__body') // ищем элемент с контентом и записываем в константу

    const getActiveTabName = () => { // объявляем функцию для получения названия активной вкладки
      return head.querySelector('.tabs__caption_active').dataset.tab // возвращаем значение data-tab активной кнопки
    }

    const setActiveContent = () => { // объявляем функцию для установки активного элемента контента
      if (body.querySelector('.tabs__content_active')) { // если уже есть активный элемент контента
        body.querySelector('.tabs__content_active').classList.remove('tabs__content_active') // то скрываем его
      }
      body.querySelector(`[data-tab=${getActiveTabName()}]`).classList.add('tabs__content_active') // затем ищем элемент контента, у которого значение data-tab совпадает со значением data-tab активной кнопки и отображаем его
    }

    // проверяем при загрузке страницы, есть ли активная вкладка
    if (!head.querySelector('.tabs__caption_active')) {  // если активной вкладки нет
      head.querySelector('.tabs__caption').classList.add('tabs__caption_active') // то делаем активной по-умолчанию первую вкладку
    }

    setActiveContent(getActiveTabName()) // устанавливаем активный элемент контента в соответствии с активной кнопкой при загрузке страницы

    head.addEventListener('click', e => { // при клике на .tabs__head
      const caption = e.target.closest('.tabs__caption') // узнаем, был ли клик на кнопке
      if (!caption) return // если клик был не на кнопке, то прерываем выполнение функции
      if (caption.classList.contains('tabs__caption_active')) return // если клик был на активной кнопке, то тоже прерываем выполнение функции и ничего не делаем

      if (head.querySelector('.tabs__caption_active')) { // если уже есть активная кнопка
        head.querySelector('.tabs__caption_active').classList.remove('tabs__caption_active') // то удаляем ей активный класс
      }

      caption.classList.add('tabs__caption_active') // затем добавляем активный класс кнопке, на которой был клик

      setActiveContent(getActiveTabName()) // устанавливаем активный элемент контента в соответствии с активной кнопкой
    })
  }

  tabs() // вызываем основную функцию

})
```

```css
body {
  background: #121212;
}
.container {
  max-width: 1140px;
  padding: 0 30px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.tabs {
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 15px;
}
.tabs__head {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.tabs__caption {
  flex: 1;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 8px 30px;
  font-size: 18px;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  color: var(--color);
  opacity: 0.6;
  background: var(--primary);
  transition: 0.25s;
}
.tabs__caption:hover {
  opacity: 0.8;
}
.tabs__caption_active {
  opacity: 1;
  background: var(--primary);
}
.tabs__body {
  background: var(--primary);
  position: relative;
  top: -2px;
  transition: 0.25s;
}
.tabs__content {
  display: none;
  padding: 30px;
  color: var(--color);
  transform: scaleY(0.8);
  opacity: 0;
  transform-origin: center top;
  -webkit-animation: showContent 0.6s forwards;
  animation: showContent 0.6s forwards;
}
.tabs__content_active {
  display: block;
}
.section {
  --primary: #3fa7d6;
  --color: #fff;
  padding: 15px 0;
}
.about {
  padding: 15px 0;
  --primary: #8cff98;
  --color: #121212;
}
@-webkit-keyframes showContent {
  0% {
    transform: scaleY(0.8);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    transform: scaleY(1);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
@keyframes showContent {
  0% {
    transform: scaleY(0.8);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    transform: scaleY(1);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
    <title>Tabs</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-reboot.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css"/>
  </head>
  <body>
    <section class="section">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="section__tabs tabs">
          <div class="tabs__head">
            <div class="tabs__caption" data-tab="home">Home</div>
            <div class="tabs__caption" data-tab="portfolio">Portfolio</div>
            <div class="tabs__caption" data-tab="about">About</div>
          </div>
          <div class="tabs__body">
            <div class="tabs__content" data-tab="home">Home lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Mollitia sit, repellat assumenda excepturi minima debitis atque nulla quibusdam iste eligendi voluptas, obcaecati nihil necessitatibus vel illum itaque ea molestias vero! Home lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Mollitia sit, repellat assumenda excepturi minima debitis atque nulla quibusdam iste eligendi voluptas, obcaecati nihil necessitatibus vel illum itaque ea molestias vero!</div>
            <div class="tabs__content" data-tab="portfolio">Portfolio lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Id magni sit, enim tenetur animi eius ea, similique optio nostrum quibusdam ex, dolores dolorem. Recusandae quo molestiae modi saepe ratione numquam!</div>
            <div class="tabs__content" data-tab="about">About lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Mollitia quibusdam nemo qui numquam magnam! In sunt, ut cum nulla, accusantium mollitia et illum voluptate repudiandae! Magnam alias, iure saepe animi.</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавил для вас более оптимизированную функцию. Вам только понадобится добавить в конец css файла следующие стили к классам. При желании можете стилизовать "активный класс" как угодно.

```
.show {
   display: block;
}

.active {
   opacity: 0.8;
}


const tabsBtn = document.querySelectorAll('.tabs__caption');
const tabsContent = document.querySelectorAll('.tabs__content');

function hideTabs() {
  tabsContent.forEach((tab) => {
    tab.classList.remove('show');
  });
}

function showTab(i) {
  tabsContent[i].classList.add('show');
}

tabsBtn.forEach((btn, i) => {
  btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    if (tabsBtn[i].classList.contains('active')) {
      tabsBtn[i].classList.remove('active');
      tabsContent[i].classList.remove('show');
    } else {
      hideTabs();
      showTab(i);

      tabsBtn.forEach((btn) => {
        btn.classList.remove('active');
      });
      tabsBtn[i].classList.add('active');
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Да, отлично. Только бы еще по клику когда таб активен он скрывался и становился неактивным... Помогите если не сложно

Comment: И да, тут получается в вашем коде активный не отследить, чтобы на него стили повесить и выделить как то..

Comment: Вы можете так же дополнить стили, я лишь привел пример как это можно реализовать, а добавить классов можно добавить сколько угодно, с любыми стилями.

Comment: Спасибо большое. Очень помогли

Comment: Кстати, в приведенном примере не получится как я понимаю добавить и удалить класс. Скрипт ведь не понимает где и что ему искать. Переменной не задано. Если я ему в showTab задаю добавление или удаление класса, то он просто ругается и говорит что не может этого сделать

Comment: Нет скрипт всё отлично отработает, он добавит прописанные вами классы, но эти классы должны реально существовать или в css, или в бутсрапе если вы его подключили. Если остались неясности, или надо доработать что-то, я помогу.

Comment: Я обновил код на ещё более гибкий, посмотрите.

Comment: Да, огромное спасибо.
Классы в css добавил.
Код обновленный тоже. Теперь он добавляет классы, но сами табы стали вести себя не совсем адекватно, переключает на первых два таба один и тот же контент, только частями...

Comment: Вопрос вот в чем, а по какому признаку скрипт определяет что нужно именно тот контент показать? По data-tab? Вроде не видел этого в нем. Мне кажется у вас и у меня сам html разный по структуре

Comment: Попробовал предыдущий вариант кода, добавив классы в стили. В первой функции отрабатывает, добавляет контенту класс, правда каждому табу контента, а вот во вторую функцию не добавляет и в консоле ошибка появляется что tab не определена

Comment: Скрипт определяет по клику. Когда мы используем querySelectorAll, в эту переменную попадают все элементы с переданным классом, и он становится псевдомассивом, и у него есть перебор, соответственно сам элемент и индекс элемента, когда кликаем в вызов функции попадает его индекс, и функция понимает с чем нужно работать. Если б я мог взглянуть на ваш код, я бы мог помочь вам. HTML я скопировал из приложенной вами ссылки, а код сам написал.

Comment: Вот сюда закинул его, там весь код впринципе можно взять <https://yola-umney.ru/>
И там же указал в шапке свой телефон, любые мессенджеры. Если сможете помочь разобраться с этим меню, то смогу как-то отблагодарить вас.